# Заполнение массива динамическими данными

Tags: java, list

Использую библиотеку *AndroidPlot* и требуется сделать график по результатам вычислений. Результаты записываются в `List<>`, но как их перенести на график?

Ругается: "expression exepted" в строчке:

```
Number[] series1Numbers = new Number[]{List<Iteration> resul};
```

Comment: Вообще, в синтаксисе таком, вроде, можно только чрез запятую числа  перечислить и всё. Попробуйте массив в цикле заполнять

Comment: Я новичок но такое не пойдет   ArrayList<Number> catnamesList = new ArrayList<Number>();
  catnamesList.add(2);
  catnamesList.add(3); 
  Number[] series1Numbers = (Number[]) catnamesList.toArray(); ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще у интерфейса `Collection`, к которому относится `List`, есть нативный метод приведения к массиву:

```
Iteration[] iterationArray = iterationList.toArray(new Iteration[iterationList.size()]);
```

Он, однако, здесь просто так не сработает - вам нужно по пути как-то преобразовать Iteration в Number, которые, насколько понимаю, друг от друга никак не наследуются. Я не уверен, может ли в этом методе производиться upcast (скорее всего, может), однако вероятнее всего вам необходимо просто в цикле перебрать список и заполнить массив.

Answer (score 2):

прописываем компонент для рисования графиков:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
    android:id="@+id/mySimpleXYPlot"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    title="A Simple XYPlot Example" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Настраиваем графики в коде:

```
package ru.alexanderklimov.test;
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.androidplot.series.XYSeries;
import com.androidplot.xy.LineAndPointFormatter;
import com.androidplot.xy.SimpleXYSeries;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

private XYPlot mySimpleXYPlot;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    // initialize our XYPlot reference:
    mySimpleXYPlot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);

    // Create a couple arrays of y-values to plot:
    Number[] series1Numbers = { 1, 8, 5, 2, 7, 4 };
    Number[] series2Numbers = { 4, 6, 3, 8, 2, 10 };

    // Turn the above arrays into XYSeries':
    // SimpleXYSeries takes a List so turn our array into a List
    XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series1Numbers),
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, // Y_VALS_ONLY means use
                                                    // the element index as
                                                    // the x value
            "Series1"); // Set the display title of the series

    // same as above
    XYSeries series2 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series2Numbers),
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series2");

    // Create a formatter to use for drawing a series using
    // LineAndPointRenderer:
    LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(
            Color.rgb(0, 200, 0), // line color
            Color.rgb(0, 100, 0), // point color
            null); // fill color (none)

    // add a new series' to the xyplot:
    mySimpleXYPlot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);

    // same as above:
    mySimpleXYPlot.addSeries(
            series2,
            new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(0, 0, 200), Color.rgb(0, 0,
                    100), null));

    // reduce the number of range labels
    mySimpleXYPlot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(3);

    // by default, AndroidPlot displays developer guides to aid in laying
    // out your plot.
    // To get rid of them call disableAllMarkup():
    mySimpleXYPlot.disableAllMarkup();
}
}
```

Любопытно, что в двух местах код был подчёркнут, указывая на устаревшие конструкции. Видимо, разработчики не успели обновить примеры на сайте в соответствии с новой документацией.

Последний штрих - в манифесте у тега application нужно прописать один атрибут:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Запускаем проект и смотрим на результат. 
Удали этот код -

```
XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series1Numbers),
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, // Y_VALS_ONLY means use
                                                    // the element index as
                                                    // the x value
            "Series1"); // Set the display title of the series

    // same as above
    XYSeries series2 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series2Numbers),
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series2");
```

И немного измени форматтер

Comment: Основная идея в том что мы приводим наш массив к List. _XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(series1Numbers),
            SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, 
            "Series1");_

Comment: По этому типу и строил, но мне нужен график по динамическим точкам, а не которые я задаю в коде.

Comment: какой тогда толк в этой строке ?  Number[] series1Numbers = new Number[]{List<Iteration> resul};

Comment: Удали следующий кусок кода, должно работать.